# How to setup templateUrl as trusted on module config?

Tags: angularjs

Consider code (Angular 1.2 RC3):

```js
main.config(['$routeProvider', '$sce', function($routeProvider, $sce) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('bla-bla.html'), controller: "App.Controllers.BlaBla" });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

It will throw an exception because services are not allowed during config and i'm using "$sce" (Strict Contextual Escaping) service here.

How to use SCE in "config" method? What is possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: This question may already have an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049261/angularjs-sce-trustasresourceurl-globally

Answer (score 1):

Angular has `$sceProvider` service whereby in privileged contexts, directives and code will bind to the result of `$sce.getTrusted(context, value)` rather than to the value directly.

Directives use `$sce.parseAs` rather than `$parse` to watch attribute bindings, which performs the `$sce.getTrusted` behind the scenes on non-constant literals.

### Away from that i think:

---

> **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants
>   can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent
>   accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully
>   configured.

---

> **Run blocks** - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be
>   injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system
>   configuration during application run time.

---

So, now $sceProvider is an inbuilt service, you can't inject your own service, or built-in services like $http into config().

### SOLUTION

Use [run()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run) instead.