# $sce.trustAsResourceUrl() globally

Tags: angularjs

How can I do something like this:
`$sce.trustAsResourceUrl('URL_HERE');`

Globally, like in the main app's `config()` or `run()` functions so that any iFrames, img src etc that have `URL_HERE` will work?

Docs are rather poor at explaining this.

Comment: For those (like me) who want to do the same thing in an up-to-date Angular 9: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927657/img-unsafe-value-used-in-a-resource-url-context

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I just read your comment from the previous answer.  Not sure if you found a solution yet. Seems you are looking for a whitelist type of thing.  I recently found this out that there's a whitelist function for $sce.

Taken from the [AngularJS docs for $sceDelegateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider):

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
 $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
   // Allow same origin resource loads.
   'self',
   // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
   'http://srv*.assets.example.com/**']);
 })
```

With this you can do string interpolation in iframes like this:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{ 'http://srv1.assets.example.com/' + url_asset }}"></iframe>
```

Comment: Still wondering what is actually the difference between * and **... :(

Comment: * says the contents of current directory and /** says the contents of this directory and all of its sub-directories downwards

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt that is incorrect. The angular source code for the sce provider is here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/0822d34b10ea0371c260c80a1486a4d508ea5a91/src/ng/sce.js#L621 and says * matches zero or more occurrences of any character other than one of the following 6 characters: '`:`', '`/`', '`.`', '`?`', '`&`' and '`;`'. ** matches zero or more occurrences of *any* character. As such, it's not appropriate for use in a scheme, domain, etc. as it would match too much.

Answer (score 74):

You could use a filter. These are available globally.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('trustUrl', function ($sce) {
    return function(url) {
      return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    };
  });
```

```
<img ng-src={{ imageHref | trustUrl }}">
```

Comment: creative use of filter very nice!

Answer (score 7):

I also liked the filter solution; however, it didn't work for me until I injected $sce properly...

```
app.filter('trustUrl', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
  return function(url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: prob coz u were minimising your code using a task runner like grunt or gulp or something - u need '$sce' when minimising

Comment: You're right, I am using grunt, and minimizing. @danday74

Answer (score 1):

I use for my videos stored on filesystem:

```
app.config( [
    '$sceDelegateProvider',
    function($sceDelegateProvider)
    {
        $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self','filesystem:**']); 
    }
]);
```