# Blocked loading resource from Open Weather

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openweathermap

working on AngularJs application and calling the Open Weather API through $resource, facing the following issue.

> Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast

**Code**

```
$scope.weatherAPI = $resource('http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast',
    { callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK' },
    { get: { method: 'JSONP' } }
);

$scope.weatherResul = $scope.weatherAPI.get({ q: $scope.srchCityName
```

Any Idea, how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to enable the URL as a trusted resource. I never use $resource, so the mechanics might be a bit different, but basically you have to inject $sce and then call  $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl('http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast'). With $resource you may be able to do this:

```
$scope.weatherAPI = $resource($sce.getTrustedResourceUrl('http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast'),
    { callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK' },
    { get: { method: 'JSONP' } }
);
```

If that doesn't work, then see this answer: [$sce.trustAsResourceUrl() globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049261/sce-trustasresourceurl-globally) for a global whitelist solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to do that just remove CALLBACK and JSONP

```
$resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/?APPID=YOURAPPID");
```