# Sanitize resource in a single controller in a globally enabled trustasresourceurl context

Tags: angularjs

As I understand `$sce` in [Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce), the default behavior is to:

> AngularJS will automatically run security checks on [sensitive HTML]
>   (sanitizations, whitelists, depending on context

Also, as I understand Whitelisting (via `$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist`)prevents sanitization.

Basically, I've got an app where trustasresourceurl is globally enabled ([see accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049261/sce-trustasresourceurl-globally)).  Now, I want to exclude 1 controller from this global trust.  In other words, I want to display this content as plain text with none of the styling bound to `ng-bind-html`:

`<span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px;"> A wizard is never late hardcode.</span>`

I may need to create a filter to manually remove any HTML, but I hate to do that just to get back to the default angular behavior.  Parsing HTML with regex is ugly and fragile.  What do you suggest?

[This code](https://codepen.io/smacky311/pen/oGNXpK?editors=1010) is close to what I want, but for whatever the style is removed so it fails to properly reproduce the problem.  I'm guessing the whitelist failed so it's still sanitized.

```js
var mainMod = angular.module('MainApp', ['ngSanitize']);

mainMod.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
      $scope.text = '<p>Hello! <a href="#">Link</a></p>';
  
      $scope.htmlContent = '<span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px;"> A wizard is never late.</span>';
}]);

angular.module('MainCtrl', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    // Allow same origin resource loads.
    'self',
    // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
    'https://codepen.io/**'
  ]);

  // The blacklist overrides the whitelist so the open redirect here is blocked.  I don't want to blocklist the whole resource.  Just this one controller.
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlBlacklist([
    ''
  ]);
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:20px;
}
.search{
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='MainApp'>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">  
    <div ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></div>
    <div ng-bind-html='text'></div>   
    
    <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px;"> A wizard is never late hardcode.  In real app this is what I get.  </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Angular 1.5.11

Comment: You can create a generic filter to get the text from html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter to get Text from HTML:

```
mainMod.filter('get_text', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
         console.log("actual HTML",text)
         var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html");
        var   textVal= doc.documentElement.textContent;
        console.log(textVal,"Only Text")
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(textVal)
    };
}]);
```

And In HTML:

```
 <div ng-bind-html="htmlContent|get_text"></div>
```

```js
var mainMod = angular.module('MainApp', ['ngSanitize']);
    
mainMod.filter('get_text', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
         console.log("actual HTML",text)
         var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html");
        var   textVal= doc.documentElement.textContent;
        console.log(textVal,"Only Text")
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(textVal)
    };
}]);

mainMod.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
      $scope.text = '<p>Hello! <a href="#">Link</a></p>';
  
      $scope.htmlContent = '<span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px;"> A wizard is never late.</span>';
}]);

angular.module('MainCtrl', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    // Allow same origin resource loads.
    'self',
    // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
    'https://codepen.io/**'
  ]);

  // The blacklist overrides the whitelist so the open redirect here is blocked.  I don't want to blocklist the whole resource.  Just this one controller.
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlBlacklist([
    ''
  ]);
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:20px;
}
.search{
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='MainApp'>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">  
    <div ng-bind-html="htmlContent|get_text"></div>
    <div ng-bind-html='text'></div>   
    
    <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px;"> A wizard is never late hardcode.  In real app this is what I get.  </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Note that as of 9/12/2017 support for `DOMParser` is poor: https://caniuse.com/#search=domparser.    My JS testing framework is imploding on it.  And the alternative `xmldom.DOMParser` gives different results from it's browser counterpart. Particularly when dealing with peer elements `<h2>visible content</h2><div>peer not displayed</div>`

Comment: For out of browser compatibility and testing I used the shim: `require('xmldom').DOMParser;`.  I imagine this could also be used for backwards compatibility.  Keep in mind the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more backwards compatibility and maybe flexibility with malformed HTML, then the following filter also works:

```
mainMod.filter('get_text', ['', function(){
    //A more forgiving HTML to text conversion
    //Wrap the content in a div and get inner text
    return function(text) {
         var doc = document.createElement('div');
         doc.innerHTML = text;
         return doc.textContent;//no need to trustAsHtml because always plain text
    };
}]);
```