# How to create a global whitelist of trusted URLs?

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

I want to implement a global whitelist functionality for safe URLs in bypassing resource URLs in Angular 2 similar to that provided by AngularJS through its $sceDelegateProvider as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24841974/9121240)

I have tried referring to the Angular docs but I can't seem to find any help.

Answer (score 0):

With angular you can use the sanitise function. Link to the document:
https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#sanitize

```
let url = this.sanitiser.sanitise(SecurityContext.URL, urlVariable);
```

This will sanitise the url.

I would also suggest you to look at the owasp website for safe url's. They have regex which has worked for me in the apst. Link below:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Validation_Regex_Repository